# Update problem NO_PUBKEY / keyserver receive failed: No data

Tags: 18.04

I tried to make a update / upgrade for Ubuntu 18.04. but the system blocks because of outdated pubkey

( The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D409AC6D65FE6664)

I found some solutions but i cant setup it

```
root@server ~ # apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D409AC6D65FE6664
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.JmsnAed5a6/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D409AC6D65FE6664
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data    

root@server ~ # apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys D409AC6D65FE6664
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.XeApVZJAVE/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys D409AC6D65FE6664
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name

root@server ~ # sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 D409AC6D65FE6664
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.2jxhY74gvK/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 D409AC6D65FE6664
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

What can i do, there are some other solutions or fixes for that? I think the pubkey is outdated or something, there are not at the keyserver, dont know what to do, normaly the programs do this by it self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[liveconfig](https://www.liveconfig.com/en/download/)

`sudo su` in the terminal
then

```
wget -O - https://www.liveconfig.com/liveconfig.key | sudo apt-key add -
apt update
```

Comment: Can you explain how this will solve the OP's issues?  Simply pasting code and a link is insufficient for an answer.

Comment: ah ok, this is a liveconfig issue? Thanks, will try it

Comment: thanks very much :-)